# How to set property of a model from a property of a `population` field in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Post` and its `author` property is set to `User` by using `ref`. Suppose there is a `country` field in `User`, how to make `Post` schema to have a `country` property as well which value is from `User.country` after population.

```
const Post = new Schema({
    text: String,
    author: {
        type: ObjectId, 
        ref: 'User'
    },
    // How to set the virtual property country which is from User.country?
});
```

I know there is a `Populate Virtuals` in Mongoose, but it seems it just another way of `populating`, it won't pick up one of the properties, but the whole referenced record. Or maybe I get it wrong?

I know I can refer the `country` from `Post.author.country`, but I want a `Post.country` as well.

How to solve this? 
Could I do this at the schema level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Populate Virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals) you can do the following :

```
var schemaOptions = {
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    }
};

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    id: false,
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, schemaOptions);

PostSchema.virtual('country').get(function() {
    return this.author.country;
});
```

Using :

```
Post.find({}).populate('author').exec(function(error, data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

it gives :

```
[{
    "_id": "59d924346be5702d16322a67",
    "text": "some text",
    "author": {
        "_id": "59d91f1a06ecf429c8aae221",
        "country": "France",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "country": "France"
}]
```

Check [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/73f478404058e737b05439f7c2cf9db6) for a full example